# Link defines which checkbox is checked on redirect

Tags: html, css

Example here : http://webintegrator.edu.ats.dk/kean0012/smartgym/
(scroll to bottom and you'll see the three prices i'm talking about)

Is it possible to define which price checkbox is checked when clicking on the corresponding price on the frontpage?

So that if i'm clicking on 209,- price on the bottom of the frontpage - that it will check the corresponding checkbox on the "tilmeld" page when redirected.

thanks.

Comment: please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it here.

Comment: It's not site "do this for me". Post what have you treid so far

Comment: @Keano You could comment, rate or mark the answer if it solved your query. Would be much appreciated. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fully functional code that will let you achieve what you require. I hope, this helps. :)

**Here's a working demo:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/3cHgLoBerPBH9Bj6RH7Y?p=preview

**Main.html**

*Change your hyperlinks to the form of **by appending ?money=value**:*

```
<a href="b.html?money=209">209</a>
<a href="b.html?money=101">101</a>
<a href="b.html?money=300">300</a>
```

**Next.html**

*Suppose your radio buttons are of the form:*

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" value="209" id="c209"> 209<br>
  <input type="radio"  value="101" id="c101"> 101<br>
  <input type="radio" value="300" id="c300"> 300
</form>
```

*Add this script to the **end of your body tag:***

```
<script>
    var value;
    var url1;
    function parseURLParams(url) {
    var queryStart = url.indexOf("?") + 1,
        queryEnd   = url.indexOf("#") + 1 || url.length + 1,
        query = url.slice(queryStart, queryEnd - 1),
        pairs = query.replace(/\+/g, " ").split("&"),
        parms = {}, i, n, v, nv;

    if (query === url || query === "") return;

    for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        nv = pairs[i].split("=", 2);
        n = decodeURIComponent(nv[0]);
        v = decodeURIComponent(nv[1]);

        if (!parms.hasOwnProperty(n)) parms[n] = [];
        parms[n].push(nv.length === 2 ? v : null);
    }
    return parms;
}
url1 = parseURLParams(window.location.href);
for(key in url1) {
    if(url1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        value = url1[key];
    }
}
document.getElementById("c"+value).checked= true;
</script>
```

> **How this works?**
>
> In the main.html you are passing the values to the URL by appending
>   the values in the url itself as `?money=209` when 209 is the value
>   that will be validated and the appropriate radio button will be
>   selected.
>
> In the next.html we have a URLparser which will extract the values
>   followed by ?money="value" and store it in the variable "Value".
>   According to this variable, we have a form with radio buttons of IDS
>   c209,c300,c101 and so on. We'll just use a simple expression:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("c"+value).checked= true;
> ```
>
> This appends "c"with the value obtained. This makes it as c209 and the
>   appropriate radio button is selected.

Answer (score 2):

Define a variable on window localStorage like:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('tmp', 'something');
```

This must work for you.